# Left , Right function

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to convert a time format 3:45 into decimal, I can get the left and right parts separately using left(text(T,"hh:mm"),2) and right(text(T,"hh:mm"),2)/60 but when I try to add he two together I just get 00:00 or a whole number.  I know there may be other ways of soling the problem but I'd like to get to the bottom of what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Convert time value to text with a decimal point in between and then to a value, VALUE(TEXT(A1,"hh.mm"))

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if the cell contains a time value, it is already a numerical type. You can verify this by doing `=ISNUMBER( T )` and if it is TRUE, then you already have a numerical value and only need to convert it to the unit measure that you want it to be.  It looks like you want the result in fractional hours, so you can simply do:

```
=T*24
```

All time values are measured in days, so you are simply multiplying it by 24 to convert it to hours.

If it turns out the your cell is text *(i.e. `=ISNUMBER( T )` is FALSE)*, then you can convert it to a time value with the TIMEVALUE function `=TIMEVALUE( T )`.  Then, likewise, you can convert that to hours like this:

```
=TIMEVALUE(T)*24
```